# Are there any interesting open questions having to do with submodularity, specially in the intersection of theoretical machine learning?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, open-problems

I was interested in knowing about open research topics related with sub modularity, specially within its intersection with theoretical machine learning (and related topics).

It seems to me that much of what I've seen, specially related with greedy algorithms and theoretical guarantees has been solved. Is there anything open questions related with theoretical guarantees that is open in sub modularity?

Comment: Could you add some tags that would connect the question to submodularity? The current tags tell nothing about the branch of mathematics the question is about.

Comment: Can someone explain why this was put on hold as off-topic? This question is about open problems in research-level mathematics!

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I didn't know what good tags to add. But it seems people already added them.

Comment: @usul I don't know why it was put on hold either, as the people that voted, left no comments and no signals for me to improve my question.

Comment: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/2152/4600

Comment: While the ultimate intent of the question is good, in its present form I think it is a bit too broad / vague. There are certainly several very specific open questions that do exist, including that of obtained "optimal" algorithms for submodular minimization, exploring connections to algebraic geometry, and much more.

Comment: I'm skeptical that the class of open questions in applications of submodularity to theoretical machine learning can be characterized as "broad", even if there are several answers.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen thank you, finally a comment that is very useful. I will look into this.

Comment: @Pinocchio, you can also try this question on cstheory.stackexchange.com, though I recommend trying to make it a bit more focused (for instance, if you care most about algorithms and optimization, mention that).

Comment: @usul, I tried asking in now, I am not sure if its good enough now, what do you think? http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/30591/are-there-any-interesting-open-questions-having-to-do-with-submodularity-specia